# Can not assign char array to string in Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, delphi-6

I have the following variable declarations:

```
arrChar_1: array[0..2] of Char;
arrChar_2: array[0..2] of Char;
str: string;
```

Then I made the assignment:

```
str := arrChar_1 + arrChar_2;
```

This assignment works normally on Delphi 6. But error occurs when I compile it on Delphi 10.2:

```
[dcc32 Error] MigrateConcatenateCharArray.dpr(26): E2008 Incompatible types
```

I'm solving this problem in the following way:

```
str := Copy(first_arrChar, 0, StrLen(first_arrChar));
str := str + Copy(second_arrChar, 0, StrLen(second_arrChar));
```

**Is there any other good solution to this problem? (1)**

---

In Delphi 6:

```
String = AnsiString
Char = AnsiChar
```

In Delphi 10.2:

```
String = UnicodeString
Char = WideChar
```

**Can tell me what caused the incompatibility issue to occur? (2)**

I'm understanding that widechar is a multi-byte character type. Unicode is the way that characters are encoded. But I'm confused about them.

Comment: I would not have expected concatenating arrays to compile in Delphi 6. IF the arrays are null-terminated (which your workaround depends on), you might get away with `str := string(arrChar_1) + string(arrChar_2);` or worst case `str := string(@arrChar_1[0]) + string(@arrChar_2[1]);` But, just for performance reasons, I would probably use `len1 := StrLen(arrChar_1); len2 := StrLen(arrChar_2); SetLength(str, len1 + len2); Move(arrChar_1, PChar(str)^, len1 * sizeof(Char)); Move(arrChar_2, (PChar(str) + len1)^, len2 * sizeof(Char));` or even `str := Format('%s%s', [arrChar_1, arrChar_2]);`

Comment: What about `str := string(arrChar_1) + string(arrChar_2);` ?

Comment: This works: `str := arrChar_1; str := str + arrChar_2;` . It seems to be a compiler error and should be reported at QP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following compiles in all versions of Delphi:

```
procedure Main;
var
  arrChar_1: array[0..2] of AnsiChar;
  arrChar_2: array[0..2] of AnsiChar;
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  str := arrChar_1 + arrChar_2;
end;
```

The following code does not compile in Unicode versions of Delphi:

```
procedure Main;
var
  arrChar_1: array[0..2] of WideChar;
  arrChar_2: array[0..2] of WideChar;
  str: UnicodeString;
begin
  str := arrChar_1 + arrChar_2;
end;
```

This seems a little odd to me. Why should the concatenation operator be supported for `AnsiChar` arrays but not `WideChar` arrays?

If you examine how the concatenation operator is implemented for `AnsiChar` arrays that begins to shed some light. The generated code first converts the arrays into `ShortString` instances. These are then converted into Delphi `AnsiString` instances. Finally the two `AnsiString` instances are concatenated.

Now, this would explain why the code fails for `WideChar` arrays. The `ShortString` type only supports `AnsiChar` elements and so a different path through the string support routines would have been needed. One can assume that the Embarcadero designers chose, for whatever reason, not to support this form of concatenation when implementing Unicode support.

To back this idea up, consider the following:

```
procedure Main;
var
  arrChar_1: array[0..254] of AnsiChar;
  arrChar_2: array[0..254] of AnsiChar;
  str: AnsiString;
begin
  str := arrChar_1 + arrChar_2;
end;
```

This compiles. But change either of the `254` upper bounds to `255` and the code fails to compile (in all versions of Delphi) reporting *E2008 Incompatible types*. That is because the array now exceeds the maximum length of a `ShortString` object.

As for how to migrate your code to Unicode Delphi, I suggest that you simply cast the character arrays to `string`:

```
str := string(arrChar_1) + string(arrChar_2);
```